# Python open json file keep in memory

Tags: json, python-3.x

Question, I have an application that accesses data in a json file. Right now, every time the application needs the data, I will open and close the file as such.

```
def access_file():
    try:
        with open(my_file, 'r') as json_data:
            json_data = json.load(json_data)
            return json_data
    except FileNotFoundError:
        logging.error("my_file not found.")
```

I am assuming it is not smart to continually be opening and closing this file so many times. How do I only open it once if it's not open and keep it open, then I can just access in memory if I need it.

Comment: If the file is not very huge you can simply preserve it in an object which is accessible in required namespaces. And there are plenty of ways to do such thing which is strongly related to the rest of your code and how you using this function in your code.

Comment: Let's say the file is huge, and will become even bigger. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Assuming your json file ever really gets too big to hold it in memory, then the problem would first occur inside the json module trying to parse it, not your code trying to hold the result in variable. So as long as `json_data` can be returned, everything is fine.

Comment: In that case you should use a database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to do it without too much overhead is to use the [standard lib's `lru_cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache). You can decorate a function with it, and it will remember the result of that function (depending on the arguments, in this case none). Next time the function is called, the result will be returned from the cache in memory, rather than re-executing the function.

As you can see in this example, this works with a very minimal addition to your code.

```
import json
from functools import lru_cache

my_file = 'foo.json'

@lru_cache(maxsize=1)
def access_file():
    try:
        with open(my_file, 'r') as json_data:
            json_data = json.load(json_data)
            return json_data
    except FileNotFoundError:
        logging.error("my_file not found.")


print(access_file())

import os
os.remove(my_file)

print(access_file())
```

Here I even remove the file to prove it really works, but I advise you not to :)
If you run this code, you'll see the content of the JSON file printed twice.

Comment: Thanks Samuel! This looks like what I need, will test this out. Quick question though, let's say my application is running and I make a json change, would I have to restart the application to clear the cache? Or should I build in a way to clear the cache?

Comment: @WhitneyChia If the JSON changes while you are running the application, you will use the old version, so you have to be careful.

Comment: @WhitneyChia Some approaches to mitigate that: 1) Keep an md5 (or some other hash) of the file content, and only look in the cache if the hash hasn't changed, 2) store the last modification date [os.path.getmtime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.getmtime) and read the file if the last modified time doesn't match the one you stored.