# How can I manage that a JSON does not always have to be open?

Tags: python, discord.py

I have what I think is a bit more difficult "problem" to solve today. In my script, I have a function which reads out a corresponding translation/record from a JSON for each executed command.

The function looks like this:

```py
response_string = {} # Gets the correct JSON from my JSON structure and reads out the correct message
def get_lang(guild, response):
    try:
        with open("languages.json", "r") as f: # Open the JSON to see which language the guild chose
            data = json.load(f) 

        return response_string[data[str(guild)]][response] # Get response from the corresponding JSON for the guild
    except:
        return response_string['english'][response] # If not set it is English
```

But here is the concern, that the JSON file is always open. This could become an issue in the end, I have been told. The JSON structure from which I get the responses looks like this:

```py
./languages # Folder
./languages/german.json
./languages/english.json
...
```

In a JSON it looks like this:

```py
{
    "all_langs": "Available Languages"
}
```

Say, for each language, there is a translation in each JSON. When running a command, I would then always call `get_lang, "all_langs"`.

I was told that it would be smart to convert the JSON to a `dict` and then read out all the translations when starting the application, so you don't always have to have the JSON open. **Is this a common or better practice?**

I have already looked at the following articles:

1. [Python open json file keep in memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50394985/python-open-json-file-keep-in-memory)
2. [Open and read latest json file one time only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61553592/open-and-read-latest-json-file-one-time-only)
3. [How to save a list to a file and read it as a list type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27745500/how-to-save-a-list-to-a-file-and-read-it-as-a-list-type)

I also started and thought about how to handle this.

```py
client.languages_loaded = False # Set it to False 

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Online")

    if client.languages_loaded:
        return
    
    client.languages_loaded = True

    client.languages = # Define all the JSON's here or start to store it in a dict?
```

But unfortunately I can't get any further, I'm more or less at the end with the knowledge, because in the end I don't know how the readout should always work without keeping the JSON open. About any tip I am grateful!

**UPDATE:**
The code I use to get the correct language JSON is the following:

```py
for i in os.listdir('./languages'):
    if i.endswith('.json'):
        with open(os.path.join('./languages', i)) as file: # Always open
            response = json.load(file) # Get the response from the correct JSON
        response_string[i.replace(".json", "")] = response # Give out response
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're trying to do would look something like this.

```
languages = {}

with open("languages.json", "r") as f: # Open the JSON
    languages = json.load(f)


response_string = {} # Gets the correct JSON from my JSON structure and reads out the correct message
def get_lang(guild, response):
    try:
        return response_string[languages[str(guild)]][response] # Get response from the corresponding JSON for the guild
    except:
        return response_string['english'][response] # If not set it is English
```

Comment: I guess this can work out in some way. In this case I would set `languages` to false before the start and in the `on_ready` event set it to `True` and read out all the data like you did?

Comment: This will not work in that way. `languages = {}` defines `language` before even using it. It is defined without any usage.

Answer (score 0):

If your json is not modified when the application run, a best practice should to have a object in memory to store this info ( a dataclass maybe).
The only drawback of that is if the json files are huge it could take a lot of memory in this case.

Alternatively you can store the same data in a mysql database and instead of reading the file you just run a mysql request to get the translation.
But I think as a good start having all translation in memory is better.

Comment: The problem here is: When I try to modify it while running, there is no way changes will be applied until the bot is restarted or something else. As I have many translations to do the JSON will for sure get bigger over time. I could try to store the translations in a database, one by one and provide the translations directly. So like: `"term_to_call" / german: "translation" / english: "translation"`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to want to modify your dictionary and not open it everytime just for reading, you can do something like this.

```py
import json

bot = commands.Bot(...)

def startup_task():
   with open('languages.json()', 'r') as file:
        bot.langauges = json.load(file)

def modify_json():
    with open('languages.json', 'w') as file:
         json.dump(bot.languages, file)

@bot.command()
async def modifydict(ctx, key, value):
    bot.languages[key] = value # modifying it in memory first
    loop = bot.loop
    await loop.run_in_executor(None, modify_json) # in case json is too big and we want to avoid blocking 
    return await ctx.send(f"Updated the json successfully with key: `{key}` and value: `value`") # modified it in the json too


@bot.command()
async def readjson(ctx, key):
    try:
       value = bot.languages[key] # you are not reading json again!
    except KeyError:
       value = None
    if not value:
       return await ctx.send(f"No such key was found in dictionary")
    return await ctx.send(f"The value of key {key} was found to be {value}")

startup_task()
bot.run("TOKEN")
```

I don't fully understand what you exactly require but I think it's something along these lines? Let me kknow if I am wrong

Comment: Your `def startup_task():` task is leading into a good direction. Maybe I need to mention this: I have some kind of undefined "function" where I determine which JSON the bot should look at. This looks like this: `with open(os.path.join('./languages', i)) as file:` and then my defined `response` is `response = json.load(file)` and then `response_string[i.replace(".json", "")] = response`. This JSON file is always open, and I do not want to have it open all the time. Possibly I can use your task to load all the JSON files into a dict and then use this? I also updated the question with the code.

Comment: one question, is the `i` here named like `english.json`, `german.json` and so on? and you want to access them without opening them everytime?

also would be easier to help for me if you could contact me on discord `Rose#1328`